# run-time error using /callcap and boost exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, runtime-error

I have to save the call tree during program execution. For that I have found the compiler switch **/callcap**. Everything works fine until I include **boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp**

I get an unhandled exception of *Access violation writing location 0x00000000* at **boost/exception/exception.hpp:216**. This is thrown even before reaching main().

I am using boost 1.51.0.

I have two simple files:

```
// main.cpp
#include <boost/exception/detail/exception_ptr.hpp>
int main()
{}
```

cap.cpp is compiled without the /callcap switch

```
  // cap.cpp
  extern "C" void __stdcall _CAP_Enter_Function(void *p)
{
}

extern "C" void __stdcall _CAP_Exit_Function(void *p) 
{
}
```

I think the problem is that all the functions in exception_ptr.hpp is to be wrapped around with the callcap functions, but unfortunately I don't know a way to switch off this functionality for the hpp only.

Have you guys any experince with such a thing, please?

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254291(v=VS.80).aspx) ?

Comment: There are little information about /callcap on the internet, so yes I have tried, however the example do not compile without the "extern C" and "__stdcall" keywords. What the linker is searching for is not the simple "void _CAP_Enter_Function(void *p)" but "extern "C" void __stdcall _CAP_Exit_Function(void *p)". It may be some other linker flag that I should switch on/off!

Comment: I have found the open-source project http://www.codeprophet.co.uk. Browsing its source I found callhooks.cpp which can use both callcaps and _penter/_pexit. Initially I tried to avoid the _penter solution, because of the manual asm prologue/epilogue thing (and _penter supports only 32bit systems). But finally _penter works for me and codeprophet's source is a good reference. However the question remains.